# Leetcode: Map Sum Pairs C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, trie

> Implement a MapSum class with insert, and sum methods.
>
> For the method insert, you'll be given a pair of (string, integer).
>   The string represents the key and the integer represents the value. If
>   the key already existed, then the original key-value pair will be
>   overridden to the new one.
>
> For the method sum, you'll be given a string representing the prefix,
>   and you need to return the sum of all the pairs' value whose key
>   starts with the prefix.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
> Input: insert("apple", 3), Output: Null
> Input: sum("ap"), Output: 3
> Input: insert("app", 2), Output: Null
> Input: sum("ap"), Output: 5
> ```

Please comment on performance and style

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TrieQuestions
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TrieMapSum
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MapSumTest()
        {
            MapSum mapSum = new MapSum();
            mapSum.Insert("apple", 3);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, mapSum.Sum("ap"));
            mapSum.Insert("app", 2);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, mapSum.Sum("ap"));
        }
    }

    public class MapSum
    {
        private TrieMSNode Head;
        /** Initialize your data structure here. */
        public MapSum()
        {
            Head = new TrieMSNode();
        }

        public void Insert(string key, int val)
        {
            var current = Head;
            foreach (var letter in key)
            {
                if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(letter))
                {
                    current.Edges.Add(letter, new TrieMSNode());
                }
                current = current.Edges[letter];
            }

            current.IsTerminal = true;
            current.Value = val;
        }

        public int Sum(string prefix)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            var current = Head;
            foreach (var letter in prefix)
            {
                if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(letter))
                {
                    return sum;
                }

                current = current.Edges[letter];
            }
            // we use dfs for each edges of the trie;
            return DFS(current);
        }

        private int DFS(TrieMSNode current)
        {
            if (current == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int sum = current.IsTerminal ? current.Value : 0;
            foreach (var edge in current.Edges.Values)
            {
                sum += DFS(edge);
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }

    internal class TrieMSNode
    {
        public Dictionary<char, TrieMSNode> Edges { get; set; }
        public bool IsTerminal;
        public int Value;

        public TrieMSNode()
        {
            Edges = new Dictionary<char, TrieMSNode>();
            IsTerminal = false;
            Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `Insert(...)` you should use `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey`for efficiency:

```
  foreach (var letter in key)
  {
    if (!current.Edges.TryGetValue(letter, out var edge))
    {
      edge = current.Edges[letter] = new TrieMSNode();
    }
    current = edge;
  }
```

---

Name your methods after what they do, not after their implementation:

> `DFS(...)`

could be `GetSumFrom(...)`

---

> ```
> public int Sum(string prefix)
> {
>   int sum = 0;
>   var current = Head;
>   foreach (var letter in prefix)
>   {
>     if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(letter))
>     {
>       return sum;
>     }
>     current = current.Edges[letter];
>   }
> ```

Here the `sum` variable is redundant because it is never changed so you could just return `0` from the loop

Again the loop can be optimized:

```
  foreach (char letter in prefix)
  {
    if (!current.Edges.TryGetValue(letter, out current))
      return 0;
  }
```

---

> ```
> DFS()
> ```

can be simplified using LINQ:

```
    private int GetSumFrom(TrieMSNode current)
{
  if (current == null)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  return current.Edges.Aggregate(current.Value, (sum, kvp) => sum + GetSumFrom(kvp.Value));
}
```

You really don't have to check for `IsTerminal` because you know that only terminal nodes have a values different from `0`.

You should test this LINQ-approach against your own plain `foreach`-loop, and you'll maybe find the latter fastest.

Comment: I've upvoted because you make some good points, but I don't understand the reasoning in the first point. Surely the edge is the `KeyValuePair<char, TrieMSNode>`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: You're right, my misinterpretation of the Dictionary concept

Answer (score 8):

I don't have much to add to Henrik's answer at a low level, but I think you've missed the point of the exercise at a high level.

The spec could be implemented as simply as

```
public class MapSum
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, int> data = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void Insert(string key, int val) => data[key] = val;

    public int Sum(string prefix) => data.Sum(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith(prefix) ? kvp.Value : 0);
}
```

The reason you instead used a trie was to avoid looping over all of the entries in `Sum`. But in the worst case `DFS` will do *exactly that*. The efficient solution is to add a field to `TrieMSNode` which caches the sum of the entire subtree rooted at that node. Updating it doesn't affect the asymptotic cost of `Insert`, just the constant. And returning it allows you to ditch `DFS` entirely, so that `Sum` is guaranteed to run in time linear in the length of the prefix.

Comment: Isn't your `sum()` implementation rather time-expensive (O(m*n)) and your storage rather memory-expensive?

Comment: @HenrikHansen, I'm not proposing that OP use the code I posted. Or was your point just that the trie is actually already not quite as bad, because its `Sum()` is only \$O(n)\$?

Comment: Just pondering but wouldn't an ordered dictionary be faster in the average case?

Comment: @MD-Tech, faster than what at which operation? But anyway, I doubt it: hashmaps are very fast for insertion of random data and for iteration, and they're the slowest overall implementation mentioned so far.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I was thinking about the prefixed sum actually. As I said I'm only pondering aloud.

Comment: Peter Taylor it is part of the TRIE excercixes in leetcode explore data structures.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of `Sum` is \$O(m n)\$,
because in the worst case it may need to enumerate all nodes.

An \$O(m)\$ implementation is possible with \$O(n)\$ extra space, and a bit of extra work in `Insert`:

- Add a `Dictionary<string, int>` to track the current values of the keys, let's call it `values`.
- Use `TrieMSNode.Value` to store the sum of all values below each node
- When inserting:

  - First check if the key replaces an existing key. Let's store in `int prev` the previous value of the key, or 0 if there was no previous value (the key is new).
  - Traverse the trie letter by letter as before, and for each node traversed, subtract `prev` and add `val`.
  - Set the new value in `values`.

Notice that the added work in `Insert` does not increase the time or space complexity.

```
public void Insert(string key, int val)
{
    var prev = values.ContainsKey(key) ? values[key] : 0;
    values[key] = val;

    var current = Head;
    foreach (var letter in key)
    {
        if (!current.Edges.ContainsKey(letter))
        {
            current.Edges.Add(letter, new TrieMSNode(val));
        }
        else
        {
            current.Edges[letter].Value -= prev;
            current.Edges[letter].Value += val;
        }
        current = current.Edges[letter];
    }
}
```

And now, the implementation of `Sum` can become simpler and faster:

```
public int Sum(string prefix)
{
    var current = Head;
    foreach (var letter in prefix)
    {
        if (!current.Edges.TryGetValue(letter, out current))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return current.Value;
}
```

Also notice that in this implementation the `TrieMSNode.IsTerminal` is no longer necessary.